# High CPU consumption

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

I’m dealing lately with more than doubled cpu consumption than normal in my multi-threaded app.
There are 4 variables that should be consistent and therefore i use ‘volatile’ key word for them.
They are just for monitoring and don’t interfere the app flow.
lately I encountered the doubled CPU consumption on my app and wondered if it’s may be the case.
for clarification all the threads are readers and writers of those variables.

Comment: You don't provide enough information. I can tell you that using `volatile` may lead to slower performance because you force the threads to read from shared cache or the memory.

Comment: what changed before consumption doubled?

Comment: You didn’t ask a question.